# CakePHP: What does the content/data come from when using -> Content For Layout

Tags: cakephp

I am still a little new to CakePHP but I do know have a good basic understanding of how it works, however a i have found something that i just can't seem to find a answer for.

I have been searching everywhere for one but I still at a lost.

Where does CakePHP get its data from when you call $content_for_layout.

I have take over a project from someone else and its be set on a number of pages but I can't seem to find anything within the app folder. I have search all the controllers, the only place i have found it was when its echoed on the screen within the view files them self's.

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

`$content_for_layout` is populated from the specific view file of the current controller/action. Look in the `app/views` folder (`app/View` for CakePHP 2) and you will see a list of folders that relate directly to the controllers, then inside each of them a bunch of `.ctp` files which relate to the controller action.

The default URL structure is `/controller/action/params` Here are a few examples:

```
URL: /products/view/12
View file: `app/views/products/view.ctp`

URL: /users/index
View file: `app/views/users/index.ctp`

Sometimes there is a prefix (for admin areas and such, this goes at the start of the URL like so:
URL: /admin/products/edit/12
View file: `app/views/products/admin_edit.ctp`
```

Hope this helps. Your URL structure may have been altered by routes, in which case dive in to `config/routes.php` to get an idea of what controller/action are being called and therefore what view files are. Read the [MVC sections of the book](http://book.cakephp.org) if you're having any more problems with CakePHP (just be sure to use the right version).

Comment: Yes I did know that, but i still don't understand, how can something (content_for_layout) be populated by a view file, when its being displayed in a view file. There is no controller for the view file I am in anyway, its just a view that loads based on user agent. A new view file loads when it sees iphone uses but the controllers that deal with that dont have any content_for_layout listed within them.

Comment: ok what you're looking at is a *layout*, `$content_for_layout` is populated by the view file somewhere the CakePHP core, you shouldn't need to worry about what goes on in the core though.

Comment: Yes, I understand that! But I don't get this setup, I can not find anything within the app itself about where hes defined content_for_layout and yet if u don't print it, the pictures it holds, do not display!

Comment: http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/view#l-489 `$content_for_layout` is set in the core `View` class, in addition to other places. Cake renders a view, then renders the layout with the view output in place of where `$content_for_layout` is.